# StencilJS | Apply host styles to component

Tags: javascript, stenciljs

I am trying to apply the styles from the website where a stencilJS component is included ... but don't know how.

```
import { Component } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'menu-component',
  styleUrl: 'menu-component.css',
  shadow: true
})

export class MyComponent {

 render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
        <p id="red">This is JSX!</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The component is included like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css" />
<script src='https://unpkg.com/component@0.0.2/dist/mycomponent.js'></script>
<my-component></my-component>
```

In my main.css file I have something like this:

```
#red{
    color: red;
}
```

I would like the style to be applied to the element from the stencil component. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [css variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties) for this. 
Look at the following code samples:

**index.html**

`<my-component style="--text-color:red;"></my-component>`

***my-component.css***

```
#red {
    color: var(--text-color, black);
}
```

In the component's styling you assign a CSS variable as value to the text color of the class `[id="red"]`. In your application, you're now able to change the color by setting the value of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

Your component has a "Shadow DOM", which serves the purpose of encapsulating everything, including styles in a separate DOM, so it pretty much exists to prevent you from overriding it's styles.

Previously there were some "shadow piercing" CSS directives like `/deep/` and `::shadow`, but they have been deprecated and are no longer functional.

So that's pretty much how it's supposed to be.

Now for workarounds:

- create a shared css file and include it in both your component and your application - or
- set the style using javascript from your host application using the shadowRoot property:

```
var div = document.querySelector('#comp').shadowRoot.querySelector('div#red');
div.style['color'] = 'red';
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for the comment. Including the css twice ... that's not an option for me. I am using an application which has the styles included automatically. Not even written by me. I tried setting `shadow: false`, but I still see the component in a `#shadow-root` dom.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `:host` psuedo selector in your stylesheet to apply host level styles:

```
:host {
    style: value
}
```

You could easily bring in `@stencil.sass` for your style sheets, link here: https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil-sass/blob/master/readme.md

This will give you greater functionality with your styles in stencil.

EDIT:

I misunderstood and now see you want to manipulate outside of the component. You could supply a `<slot />` element in your web component and add specifically styled elements from outside of the web components DOM. Link here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/slot

Comment: Hi. I don't think I asked the right way. So let's say that I use Bootstrap in a project and I want to use a Bootstrap element in a Stencil component. Will I have to add the  bootstrap css to my component as well? Or can I just create the component and have it render using the original bootstrap css found in the project?

Comment: @Ciprian did you find a solution to use bootstrap in stencil component?

Comment: @Dark_Knight No. Sorry